# How to wait for a response when running a command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Why is it not waiting for a response? it just runs the whole code
Someone told me filter is part of v13 collector options, is there anyway to do this then?

```
const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!target) return message.reply("you have to mention somebody");
    
        await message.reply(
          `you proposed to ${target}! Is it **YES** or **NO**?`
        );
    
        const filter = (m) =>
          m.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("yes") &&
          !m.author.bot &&
          m.author.target;
    
        const main = message.guild.channels.resolve("706263571562102835");
    
        main.awaitMessages(filter, {
          errors: ["time"],
          max: 1,
          time: 900000,
        });
    
        await message.reply(
          `You e ${target} are now married!`
        );
      },
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

`message.author.target` does not exist. I believe what you meant to do is

```js
const filter = (m) =>
          m.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("yes") &&
          !m.author.bot &&
          m.author.id == target.id
```

This means that the filter will only detect messages which: begin with "yes", when the author is not a bot, and when the author's ID the same as the target's ID.